# How to prioritise delete and update based on timestamp during replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, merge-replication, merge

We have two MS SQL Server 2012 servers running merge replication. 
We have used the SQL Server DATETIME (Later Wins) Conflict Resolver to resolve conflicts based on the latest updated time.

However, in case of row deletion, the delete operation always takes priority. Example:

- On the publisher a row is deleted at 10:00 hrs.
- On the subscriber the same row gets updated at 11:00 hrs.
- My synchronisation cycle started at 11:30 hrs.

The default behaviour here was to delete the row. However, we wanted the row to be updated at the publisher from subscriber data, as per the last modified time. How to achieve that result in such scenarios?

Comment: so, you want the row "undeleted" on the publisher?

Comment: yes @MaxVernon , for the above scenario .In general what i was  trying to achieve here is whatever happens later gets the preference